# MongoDB database cleaner for Nightwatch.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

Is there any way of wiping a mongo database in between Nightwatch e2e tests?

I'm coming from Ruby, where you can configure RSpec to use a package called [database cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) and wipe your db after each test, and I'm wondering if a similar setup exists in the javascript ecosystem.

I did some research and found a promising-looking package called [node-database-cleaner](https://github.com/emerleite/node-database-cleaner), but at present it is throwing an error.

Code:

```
require('mongodb');
const DatabaseCleaner = require('database-cleaner');
const databaseCleaner = new DatabaseCleaner('mongodb');

...test assertions

databaseCleaner.clean('mongodb://localhost:27017/my-db')
```

Error:
`TypeError: db.collections is not a function`

I'm not bound to using node-database-cleaner—I'd be interested in any solution no matter what library it uses.